# Change document root folder in shared server with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, document-root, public-html

I'm the admin of an apache server (on a hosting package that allows me to host multiple domains), I've got one domain in `public_html` (let's call it www.ROOTwebsite.com) and 9 other domains hosted in a folder in the same directory level as the `public_html`, called `DOMAINS`.

So the structure is:

```
-DOMAINS/site1.com/
        /site2.com/ ... etc
-public_html
```

I'm using `'/'` in the beginning of all relative paths in wamp for `site1.com` (for example /menu.php) and it works fine, but when I upload to DOMAINS/site1.com/ it messes up the site because it obviously is looking at the `public_html` directory as the ROOT.

I've used a number of combinations on the following in the .htaccess file, but I can't figure out which is the right syntax to change the ROOT to a directory sitting **NEXT** to public_html, not under it as usual:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ROOTwebsite.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ROOTwebsite.gr$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !DOMAINS/site1.com/
RewriteRule (.*) /DOMAINS/site1.com/$1 [L]
```

I wish to change the root directory for `site1.com` so that it also works with the `'/'`, without affecting the `public_html` website.

Can anyone see the problem with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redefine the document root via .htaccess. You have to create different vhosts for the domains that then can have separate document roots.

Comment: My problem is the online management on the shared server. How can I host the sites in the DOMAINS folder in vhosts?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I have come to redefine a document root via .htaccess is the following (not exactly what you are asking, because in my example, site1.com is a subdir of the main document root, but this would achieve what you want, with the caveat below).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^site1.com/ /site1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

this will effectively redirect all site1.com to the site1.com subdirectory. 
[caveat] The only problem I could not solve is how to redirect an url that goes directly to the subdirectory such as http://site1.com/site1.com/index.html to http://site1.com/index.html